# What does 'Half-Offeus' mean?

Tags: meaning

Recently I happened to watch Married With Children Ep 507. In that episode, the dad (Al Bundy) was explaining why he took a header by a granite statue in the wishing pond:

> ...when I slipped on some wishing-pond slime, and took a header
>   right into the granite statue of the goddess of the malls: Half-Offeus.

I don't understand what 'half-offeus' means.
Could anybody help me out on this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. It would be heard as "half-off"  (in other words, a discount of 50%) plus _eus_ to make it sound like a god such as Morpheus, or Prometheus. It would be readily understood by a native speaker, but possibly opaque to a non-native speaker.

Comment: Note that malls, AKA shopping malls, often have sales, like a half-off sale. So the god of malls might be called "half-offeus".

Answer (score 14):

***Half-Offeus*** is probably a nonce; in other words, a "one-off", and so impossible to find in a dictionary.

It would be heard as "half-off" (in other words, a discount of 50%) plus *eus* to make it sound like a god such as Morpheus, or Prometheus. It would be readily understood by a native speaker, but possibly opaque to a non-native speaker.

This is probably an example of ***productivity*** in linguistics, a situation in which native speakers use a certain type of creativity (and some intuitive grammatical process)  to express new ideas during word formation.

With the exception of *schm* reduplication and zero-derivation, there is little room for productivity in English, unless you are writing sitcoms for television, or struggling to express something in everyday speech for which there is no adequate word.

Comment: I know some users will no doubt take exception to my posting an answer on this; I felt it was interesting based on the _productivity_ issue. I have posted one or two thingies on this, and felt it worthwhile.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean exactly by “_such_ productivity” – do you mean productivity of a specific type? If so, which one? There are many processes in English which are completely productive (e.g., zero-derivation).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sorry...I mis-spoke myself. Thanks. Will edit. English is not generally considered to be a _productive_ language, in comparison with other languages. As far as I know, English productivity is usually in verbing a noun, and obvious.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thinking it through some more, I think what I meant was this _particular_ type of productivity, that of adding _eus_ to a commonly used word. It is not a recognized form of productivity (as zero-derivation is.)

Comment: No, _-eus_ is definitely not productive. But I don’t think there’s anything less productive about English than most other languages. There are lots of productive processes in English; new words can be productively formed in a wide array of ways – no fewer than any other language I can think of. (And it doesn’t really make sense to describe a language as productive: _processes_ are productive, meaning they can be freely applied in circumstances they hadn’t been used in before; that doesn’t apply to a whole language.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I know you have more languages than I do, and  I would tend to agree: I have always thought of English as _very_ productive, but I am relying on other linguists who have argued the opposite. At the moment I am struggling to find an authority to support this idea.  Meanwhile, take the example of the Spanish _despectivo_ and all its infinite derivations. There are definite  guidelines, and so would seem to follow some form of intuitive grammar. Also we have _re-_ added to whatever adjective to mean "very". These are examples of free productivity. Sorry for my lack of clarity.

Comment: On the other hand, I have to disagree on one point: [Language _is_ a process.](https://www.startpage.com/do/search?cat=web&language=english&query=language+as+a+process&pl=opensearch)

Comment: Language is a process, yes, arguably – but _a_ language is not, at least not in the same way. As a process, language itself is inherently productive; I just don’t see how describing _a_ language as productive really makes sense, unless you mean how English is more ‘productive’ (i.e., able to develop through natural usage) than, say, Mycenaean or Etruscan. As for _despectivo_, I can think of _despectivamente_, _despectividad_, _despectivar_ (with derivations), all of which work in English too for _despective_: _despectively_, _despectivity_, _despectivise_ (or just _despect_).

Comment: Sorry, @JanusBahsJacquet, what i meant was the _sufijo despectivo_ ...like _madrastra_ (from madre). There is no English equivalent, that I know. See my post on [SP](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/c%c3%b3mo-formar-un-despectivo)

Comment: Oh, I see; you mean derivation through pejorative suffixation. No, English doesn’t really have that, though there are some pejorative suffixes for people (_-ster_, _-tard_). On the other hand, English is, as far as I know, unique in having expletive infixation (_abso-bloody-lutely_) as a productive process.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ...this should probably go to chat, and invite some grammarians that have a few languages. I think maybe the larger question coming here is _which_ languages have _more_ possibilities for morphological changes "spur of the moment" based on an intuitive grammar. Personally, I don't do well at chat. I think there is good question hiding here; however, it may belong on Linguistics.SE

Comment: Prometheus was a Titan, not a god. Perhaps it would be more accurate to claim that the "-eus" suffix evokes Greek mythology in general.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I seriously doubt that Al was educated enough to make that distinction. Then this would become an argument of _register_.

Comment: Aren't many neologisms created using productions like this? E.g. all the *e-* words for Internet variations on traditional processes (email, evite) and the *-gate* suffix for scandals? Or is this something else?

Comment: @Cascabel Anyway, '-us' is a masculine ending in Latin, so he should have said 'god' - or made it Half-Offea.